# Power Query Applying a Function Across Every Column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, excel-2016, m

I am trying to write a query that takes a table and multiplies every number in the table by 100.  I've gotten close, but I am having trouble applying it correctly to every column.  Below is the code I have so far.  The line starting with *ReplaceTable* is the line I have working for one column, and the line below was my attempt at getting it to work for other columns. I am dealing with a small subset currently, but the real data will potentially have ~100 columns, so I do not want to do this by hand.  If there's a better way to do this task, please let me know.  I am new to Power Query, so if able please explain my error/the solution so I can learn.  Thanks!

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    //Organization will always be of type text.  The others will be should be numbers, unless user error
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Organization", type text}, {"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", Int64.Type}}),
   //function to replace all values in all columns with multiplied values
   MultiplyReplace = (DataTable as table, DataTableColumns as list) =>
     let
        Counter = Table.ColumnCount(DataTable),
        ReplaceCol = (DataTableTemp, i) =>
            let
                colName = {DataTableColumns{i}},
                col = Table.Column(DataTableTemp, colName),
                //LINE THAT WORKS- want this functionality for ALL columns
                ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(DataTableTemp, each[A], each if [A] is number then [A]*100 else [A], Replacer.ReplaceValue, colName)
                //ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(DataTableTemp, each col, each if col is number then col*100 else col, Replace.ReplaceValue, colName)
            in
                if i = Counter-1 then ReplaceTable else @ReplaceCol(ReplaceTable, i+1)
     in
        ReplaceCol(DataTable, 0),
    allColumns = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Multiplied Numerics" = MultiplyReplace(#"Changed Type", allColumns)
    //#"Restored Type" = Value.ReplaceTypes(#"Multiplied Numerics", #"Changed Type")
in
    #"Multiplied Numerics"
```

Comment: The code works fine for 1 column (column A in the example).  I need to apply it to every column in the table, however.  I have the line commented out that is my attempt at doing this.
So, at the end of running the code, columns A, B, and C should all have been multiplied by 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue involves the scope of the functions and the variables.

With a hard-coded column name (such as [A]), the code is understanding the shorthand to actually mean `_[A]`. Within a `Table.ReplaceValue` function, that `_` is referencing the current Record or row. However, the `col` variable is referencing the *entire* table column. When used in the replacer function, it causes an error. *(Unfortunately(?), errors in replacer functions are just ignored with no error message, so issues can be hard to trace.)*

In the corrected code, I got rid of the `col` variable, since it's being determined at the wrong scope level. I changed `colName` to being text instead of a list, and then used the `Record.Field` function with `_` (the current record within the `Table.ReplaceValue` function) and the text value `colName` to extract the desired record for the calculations with the `Table.ReplaceValue` function itself.

**Corrected Code**

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    //Organization will always be of type text.  The others will be should be numbers, unless user error
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Organization", type text}, {"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", Int64.Type}}),
   //function to replace all values in all columns with multiplied values
   MultiplyReplace = (DataTable as table, DataTableColumns as list) =>
     let
        Counter = Table.ColumnCount(DataTable),
        ReplaceCol = (DataTableTemp, i) =>
            let
                colName = DataTableColumns{i},
                //LINE THAT WORKS- want this functionality for ALL columns
                ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(DataTableTemp,each Record.Field(_, colName), each if Record.Field(_, colName) is number then Record.Field(_, colName)*100 else Record.Field(_, colName),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{colName})
                //ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(DataTableTemp, each col, each if col is number then col*100 else col, Replace.ReplaceValue, colName)
            in
                if i = Counter-1 then ReplaceTable else @ReplaceCol(ReplaceTable, i+1)
     in
        ReplaceCol(DataTable, 0),
    allColumns = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Multiplied Numerics" = MultiplyReplace(#"Changed Type", allColumns)
    //#"Restored Type" = Value.ReplaceTypes(#"Multiplied Numerics", #"Changed Type")
in
    #"Multiplied Numerics"
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you so much!  I really appreciate the explanation of _ as well.  Helped clear up what was happening in the Record.Field function.

Comment: @Zoopzoop You're welcome. The tricky bit with `_` is that it's meaning can change depending on the function it's being used with. I've had some table-level functions where `_` means a specific field instead of a record.